# Can I use "they'd" as in "they'd many cars"?

Tags: contractions

I'm writing a poem so perhaps it doesn't matter, but I also want to know if you'd easily understand what I mean.

Comment: As it stands, as a native English speaker I don't understand what you mean by "they'd many cars". You need a verb in there to make sense of it.

Comment: @Roy I se it as they had many cars

Comment: @Mark On its own that just sounds strange IMO, as part of a larger sentence it could make sense but purely as the fragment given it's unclear at least to my understanding of it.

Comment: I immediately understood *they'd* to stand for *they had*. Particularly in the case of a poem, it seems reasonable.

Comment: @JasonBassford we both agree on "they had", but the ambiguity is whether "had" means "possessed" or it's an auxiliary verb. When I read it, I assumed there's an error and the participle had accidentally been omitted, e.g. "they'd *seen* many cars". The context might resolve this, eg "they'd many cars to choose from" is fine.

Answer (score 4):

The general rule is that when 'to have' is the main verb, you don't abbreviate it but when it is the auxiliary verb you may do so.

For example:

> They'd many cars (incorrect - main verb)
>
> They'd owned many cars (correct - auxiliary verb)

There may be exceptions but they are unusual.

Comment: The first seems reasonable to me as a UK English speaker. For example if they had cars they did not own. OK i is speaking fast and not what you would write but understandale.